# Найти в списке все ближайшие по значению числа к переданному числу

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Задание**
Написать код с помощью функции, которая должна найти в списке все ближайшие по значению числа  к числу x и вернуть список таких чисел. Если таких чисел нет, функция должна вернуть None

Сравнение чисел c точностью 0.00001

**Мой решение**

```
def solve(numbers, x):
    L=[]
    k=0.00001
    item=0
    while item < len(numbers):
        if (abs(numbers[item]-x)) < k:
            L.append(numbers[item])
        item+=1  
    if L!=[]: print(L)
    else: return None

numbers1=[float(e) for e in input().split(',')]
x1=float(input())
solve(numbers1,x1)
```

Код работает, но есть ли возможность записать его более правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно так:

```
def solve(numbers, x):
    arr=[]
    k=0.00001
    for el in numbers:
        if abs(el - x) < k:
            arr.append(el)
    if arr:
        return arr

numbers1=[float(e) for e in input().split(',')]
x1=float(input())
print(solve(numbers1,x1))
```

либо так:

```
def solve(numbers, x):
    k=0.00001
    arr = [el for el in numbers if abs(el - x) < k]
    if arr:
        return arr
```